# MemoryError in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have file 1.csv, a file that has 5 gb of memory. And I have pandas scipt for removing duplicates. But each time I run script I get memory error.

I tried chunking the large file, but it can only read the file in parts.  I need to remove duplicates from whole file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('1.csv',na_filter=False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['job_title','industry','state','company_name'])

df.to_csv('2.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8')
```

I expect to get 2.csv file but I get this instead

> File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
>     File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 919, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory . 
>     File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2141, in pandas._libs.parsers._concatenate_chunks
>   MemoryError

Comment: `df = df.drop_duplicates(['job_title','industry','state','company_name'])` or `df.drop_duplicates(['job_title','industry','state','company_name'], inplace=True)`

Comment: @jezrael I have problem with big file, not with removing duplicates, because file is 5gb

Comment: You could use `csv.reader` within `open` and read one row at a time. Make it as a temp df and concatenate it with your main df using `pd.concat().drop_duplicates(by=['job_title','industry','state','company_name'])`

Comment: @kavin can you please write that code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you working in bash and need a quick fix, you could use the commands where [line number] is the amount of lines you want each file to have

```
split -l [line number] file.csv
```

and then later join files

```
cat file1.csv <(tail +2 file2.csv) > out.csv
```